# Container won't update its boarder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I have a page I'm working on where I an API sending information back to the page and updating the information on the page. But I wan't the information to be displayed in a certain way, i.e I want a boarder around the container. I've tried altering the .css and the .js files associated as well as other attributes like the background color and for the life of me, I can't make a border appear.

Here is a link to the part of my code I can't get o work.
http://www.bootply.com/VejUDSbYRa

Answer (score 1):

```
 .resultWrapper{

  background-color: #061A1B;
  border: 1px #8EA7AE solid;
 }
```

If you don't specify style of the border, how will it know what to make?